# upload csv to mysql selected columns only - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, import-from-csv

Want to upload CSV file into MySQL Database, upload only selected columns other will be blank when the upload has an option to select the column or field want to upload and upload only selected, how can I do that anybody has any solution

Comment: no tried multiple things but not worked, I got success to upload CSV to DB the choose option still not working, I want to choose option like vicidial software to have to upload data, when you select csv they give option to select the field want to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some library to export/import to excel/csv files to database.

There is a lot of solutions. 
You can use for example:
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/

You can install this package by Composer.

Usage:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class UsersImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
           'name'     => $row[0],
           'email'    => $row[1], 
           'password' => Hash::make($row[2]),
        ]);
    }
}
```

How to import certain columns?
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class UsersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            User::create([
                'name' => $row[0], // Here select ROW - 0 is the first row from your CSV
            ]);
        }
    }
}

public function import() 
{
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: okay tried, the CSV file uploaded to MySQL but I want to give an option to the user to select the fields to want to upload like I have 10 fields but the user wants to upload only 5 so user choose the fields and upload.

Comment: You can do this by this library, Just read carefully. It has this kind of option.

Comment: I tried everything. and working and i don't have any idea how to do that

Comment: Take a look, I updated answer. As I told you i t was in doc.